# PHP count and sum preg_matches

Tags: php, preg-match

So... I have a problem with counting all ccurrences of preg_match and summing/addition first parts of it (number before "/"). I just want to get the average of numbers before "/". Really sorry for bad english.

script.php

```
$wyniki=file("wyniki.txt");
foreach($wyniki as $w)
{
        preg_match("/^([0-9]{1})\/([0-9]{1})$/",$w,$ar);
        if(!empty($ar)){
        print_r($ar[1].'/'.$ar[2]);
        echo("\n");
        }
}
```

script2.php (fail, but other way of script.php)

```
$file=fopen("wyniki.txt", "r");
$read=fread($file, filesize("wyniki.txt"));
echo($read."\n");
//if($read!=trim(''))
//{
        preg_match("/^([0-9]{1})\/([0-9]{1})$/",$read,$ar);
        //print_r($ar[1].'/'.$ar[2]);
        print_r($ar);
        echo("\n");
//}
fclose($file);
```

wyniki.txt

```
5/5
asd

4/5
fgh
```

Comment: Tip: `[0-9]{1}` can be written as `[0-9]` alone. Adding `{1}` is kinda like saying "an apple is an apple". The character class will already match a single digit on its own.

Comment: What's  your pb here? Your regexp looks OK (cf http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html)

Comment: My problem here is to create code for getting the average. All my tries even with counting $ar failed ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex seems ok. Perhaps you have some whitespace in the end of each line (you have used '$'). You can delete these by using trim(). Additionally, regex might not be the best solution in every case. Perhaps it would be simpler for you to test for the occurrence of '/', then use split() and check it the array[0] is a number (is_numeric()). Consider the following code:

```
$wyniki=file("wyniki.txt");
foreach($wyniki as $w) {
 if (strpos($w, '/') !== FALSE) {
  $tarr = split("\/", $w);
  if (is_numeric($tarr[0]))
   echo "This is a number: " . $tarr[0];
 }
}
```

Second code with regex:

```
$flines = array("5/5","asd","4/5","fgh");
$regex = "#^([0-9]{1})\/([0-9]{1})$#";
$res = $tot = 0;
foreach ($flines as $fline) {
$arr = array();
preg_match($regex, $fline, $arr);
if (is_numeric($arr[1])) {
    $res += $arr[1];
    $tot++;
}
}
$avg = bcdiv($res, $tot, 2);
echo "Average: $avg";
```

Comment: that's right, but I still don't know how to count all occurences ;) And also how to sum the numbers before / ;)

Comment: I've edited my code which gives 4.5 correctly. This assumes that all your numbers behind the '/' are equal.

Comment: 4.5? Yes, numbers after '/' are always 5, but before not ;)

Comment: 4.5 was the result for my test (4+5=9;9/2=4.5). Obviously, you have to change the flines part in order to suit your needs.

Comment: yeah ;P I already did it and also I've changed $avg part to $res / $tot;